# list columns, diplaying information provided via lookup from one column differently in another

Tags: list, column, custom

There is a lookup column within my list that allows the results to be displayed in many different ways. Example: Smith, John W or John.Smith or Employee ID#. Is there a way to add another column to display both values without the EU needing to perform a second lookup?

Column I (lookup) - display as (show field: Name) Smith, John W
Column II (show field: Employee ID) from column I

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to column settings, and you will find a list of checkboxes with columns from referenced list. You will be able to select any column that you wish to display.